# Error during program installation using Synaptic Package manager

Tags: software-installation

I tried to download and install the Pixillion Image Converter Software from the Synaptic Package Manager. It downloaded and started to install. Then the message below appeared.

> W: Download is performed unsandboxed as root as file ‘/var/cache/apt/archives/partial/python3-problem-report_2.20.4-0ubuntu4.8_all.deb’ couldn’t be accessed by user ‘_apt’. - pkgAcquire::Run (13: Permission denied)

I am using Lubuntu 17.04 and Mozilla Fiefox

Comment: Could you post the exact command you used?

Comment: It is known [bug 1522675](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1522675), after long discussion with developers it is fixed.  Please wait some hours or one-two days.